# R - Need help speeding up a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, vectorization, data.table

I have two dataframes; one is 48 rows long and looks like this:

name = Z31

```
     Est.Date   Site    Cultivar   Planting
1   24/07/2011  Birchip Axe           1
2   08/08/2011  Birchip Bolac         1
3   24/07/2011  Birchip Derrimut      1
4   12/08/2011  Birchip Eaglehawk     1
5   29/07/2011  Birchip Gregory       1
6   29/07/2011  Birchip Lincoln       1
7   23/07/2011  Birchip Mace          1
8   29/07/2011  Birchip Scout         1
9   17/09/2011  Birchip Axe           2
10  19/09/2011  Birchip Bolac         2
```

The other is > 23000 rows and contains output from a simulator. It looks like this:

name = pred

```
    Date        maxt    mint    Cultivar    Site    Planting    tt  cum_tt
1   5/05/2011   18       6.5    Axe        Birchip  1        12.25  0
2   6/05/2011   17.5     2.5    Axe        Birchip  1        10     0
3   7/05/2011   18       2.5    Axe        Birchip  1        10.25  0
4   8/05/2011   19.5       2    Axe        Birchip  1        10.75  0
5   9/05/2011   17       4.5    Axe        Birchip  1        10.75  0
6   10/05/2011  15.5    -0.5    Axe        Birchip  1        7.5    0
7   11/05/2011  14       5.5    Axe        Birchip  1        9.75   0
8   12/05/2011  19         8    Axe        Birchip  1        13.5   0
9   13/05/2011  18.5     7.5    Axe        Birchip  1        13     0
10  14/05/2011  16       3.5    Axe        Birchip  1        9.75   0
```

What I want to do is have the cum_tt column start to add the tt column of the current row to the cum_tt of the previous row (cumulative addition) ONLY if the date in the pred DF is equal to or greater than the Z31 est.Date. I have written the following for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Z31)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(pred)){
    if (Z31[i,]$Site == pred[j,]$Site & Z31[i,]$Cultivar == pred[j,]$Cultivar & Z31[i,]$Planting == pred[j,]$Planting &
        pred[j,]$Date >= Z31[i,]$Est.Date)
    {
      pred[j,]$cum_tt <- pred[j,]$tt + pred[j-1,]$cum_tt
    }
  }
}
```

This works but it is so slow it will take about an hour to run the entire set. I know loops are not R's strong point so can anyone assist me with vectorising this operation?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

Here's the output from dput(Z31):

`structure(list(Est.Date = structure(c(15179, 15194, 15179, 15198, 
15184, 15184, 15178, 15184, 15234, 15236, 15230, 15238, 15229, 
15236, 15229, 15231, 15155, 15170, 15160, 15168, 15165, 15159, 
15170, 15170, 15191, 15205, 15198, 15203, 15202, 15195, 15203, 
15206, 15193, 15193, 15195, 15200, 15193, 15205, 15200, 15205, 
15226, 15245, 15231, 15259, 15241, 15241, 15241, 15241), class = "Date"), 
    Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Birchip", "Gatton", 
    "Tarlee"), class = "factor"), Cultivar = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L), .Label = c("Axe", "Bolac", "Derrimut", "Eaglehawk", 
    "Gregory", "Lincoln", "Mace", "Scout"), class = "factor"), 
    Planting = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Est.Date", "Site", 
"Cultivar", "Planting"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")`

Here's pred. Note there are some extra colums here. I've just included the relevant ones above for ease of reading.

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15099, 15100, 15101, 15102, 
15103, 15104, 15105, 15106, 15107, 15108, 15109, 15110, 15111, 
15112, 15113, 15114, 15115, 15116, 15117, 15118), class = "Date"), 
    flowering_das = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Zadok = c(9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11.032, 11.085, 
    11.157), stagename = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("emergence", 
    "end_grain_fill", "end_of_juvenil", "floral_initiat", "flowering", 
    "germination", "maturity", "out", "sowing", "start_grain_fi"
    ), class = "factor"), node_no = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2.032, 2.085, 2.157), maxt = c(18, 
    17.5, 18, 19.5, 17, 15.5, 14, 19, 18.5, 16, 16, 15, 16.5, 
    16.5, 20.5, 23, 25.5, 16.5, 16.5, 15), mint = c(6.5, 2.5, 
    2.5, 2, 4.5, -0.5, 5.5, 8, 7.5, 3.5, 6, 1, 5.5, 2, 7, 7, 
    9, 13.5, 11.5, 8.5), Cultivar = c("Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", 
    "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", 
    "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe", "Axe"), Site = c("Birchip", 
    "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", 
    "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", 
    "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", "Birchip", 
    "Birchip"), Planting = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1"), `NA` = c("Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", 
    "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", 
    "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", 
    "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", 
    "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", 
    "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", 
    "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out", "Birchip TOS1 Axe.out"
    ), tt = c(12.25, 10, 10.25, 10.75, 10.75, 7.5, 9.75, 13.5, 
    13, 9.75, 11, 8, 11, 9.25, 13.75, 15, 17.25, 15, 14, 11.75
    ), cum_tt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Date", "flowering_das", "Zadok", 
"stagename", "node_no", "maxt", "mint", "Cultivar", "Site", "Planting", 
NA, "tt", "cum_tt"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

UPDATE

Thanks everyone for your help. I'm still new to the vector way of doing things and I wasn't able to implement some of the more complex solutions in time. I've got some timing below for the way Subs suggested. It's fast enough now to do what I need. These number are in seconds for one iteration of Z over P.

my way: 59.77

Subs: 14.62

Subs using numeric date: 11.12

Comment: Can you please update your question with the results of `dput(Z31)` and `dput(pred)`? I can't get your code to run as is after reading the text in...

Comment: FYI this also looks like `data.table()` and `roll = TRUE` would be faster.

Comment: As above with regards to dput output. Had a look at data.table... that might be something to explore after lunch :)

Comment: `dput(head(pred,20))` should do the trick :)

Comment: *bonk* of course... Here you go :) Off to eat now.

Comment: If you want to compare the `Dates`, why don't you convert them to a vector instead of `Class Date`. It is easy to sort and compare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure that we can do this in a few seconds... my first answer on here so go gentle!

```
## first make sure we have dates in a suitable format for comparison
## by using strptime, creating the columns estdate_tidy and date_tidy
## in Z31 and pred respectively

Z31$estdate_tidy = strptime(as.character(Z31$Est.Date), "%d/%m/%Y")
pred$date_tidy = strptime(as.character(pred$Date), "%d/%m/%Y")

## now map the estdate_tidy column over to pred using the match command -
## Z31_m and pred_m are dummy variables that hopefully make this clear

Z31_m = paste(Z31$Site, Z31$Cultivar, Z31$Planting)
pred_m = paste(pred$Site, pred$Cultivar, pred$Planting)
pred$estdate_tidy = Z31$estdate_tidy[match(pred_m, Z31_m)]

## then define a ttfilter column that copies tt, except for being 0 when
## estdate_tidy is after date_tidy (think this is what you described)

pred$ttfilter = ifelse(pred$date_tidy >= pred$estdate_tidy, pred$tt, 0)

## finally use cumsum function to sum this new column up (looks like you
## wanted the answer in cum_tt so I've put it there)

pred$cum_tt = cumsum(pred$ttfilter)
```

Hope this helps :)

**UPDATE (7 June):**

The vectorised code to tackle the new specification - i.e. that the cumsum should be done separately for each set of conditions (Site/Cultivar/Planting) - is shown below:

```
Z31$Lookup=with(Z31,paste(Site,Cultivar,Planting,sep="~"))
Z31$LookupNum=match(Z31$Lookup,unique(Z31$Lookup))
pred$Lookup=with(pred,paste(Site,Cultivar,Planting,sep="~"))
pred$LookupNum=match(pred$Lookup,unique(pred$Lookup))

pred$Est.Date = Z31$Est.Date[match(pred$Lookup,Z31$Lookup)]
pred$ttValid = (pred$Date>=pred$Est.Date)
pred$ttFiltered = ifelse(pred$ttValid, pred$tt, 0)

### now fill in cumsum of ttFiltered separately for each LookupNum
pred$cum_tt_Z31 = as.vector(unlist(tapply(pred$ttFiltered,
                                          pred$LookupNum,cumsum)))
```

Runtime is 0.16 seconds on my machine, and the final `pred$cum_tt_Z31` column matches exactly with the answer from the non-vectorised code :)

For completeness, it's worth noting that the final complicated tapply line above can be replaced by the following simpler approach with a short loop over the 48 possible cases:

```
pred$cum_tt_Z31 = rep(NA, nrow(pred))
for (lookup in unique(pred$Lookup)) {
    subs = which(pred$Lookup==lookup)
    pred$cum_tt_Z31[subs] = cumsum(pred$ttFiltered[subs])
}
```

The runtime only increases slightly to 0.25 seconds or so, because the loop here is very small and the work done inside the loop is vectorised.

Think we've cracked it! :)

**Some quick observations on vectorisation (8 June):**

The process of vectorising the steps of the process brought runtime down from close to an hour to 0.16 seconds in total. Even allowing for different machine speeds, this is a speedup by at least a factor of 10,000, which dwarfs the factors of 2-5 one might get from making minor tweaks but still retaining a loop structure.

The first key observation to make: in the solution, every line creates - without looping - an entire new vector with the same length as the columns in Z31 or pred. For neatness, I often find it useful to create these new vectors as new data frame columns, but obviously this is not strictly necessary.

Second observation: the required Est.Date column gets transferred correctly from Z31 to pred using a "paste'n'match" strategy. There are alternative approaches to this sort of task (e.g. using merge), but I take this route as it is completely failsafe and guarantees to preserve the order in pred (which is crucial). Essentially the paste operation just lets you match up several fields at once, because if the pasted strings match then all their constituent parts match. I use ~ as a separator (provided I know that symbol won't appear in any of the fields) to avoid the paste operation causing any ambiguity. If you use a space separator, then pasting together something like ("A B", "C", "D") would give the same result as pasting ("A", "B C", "D") - and we want to avoid any headaches!

Third observation: it's easy to vectorise logical operations such as seeing if one vector exceeds another (see pred$ttValid), or choosing one value or another based on the value of a vector (see pred$ttFiltered). In the current situation, these could be combined into one line, but I broke things down a little more as a demonstration.

Fourth observation: the final line that creates pred$cum_tt_Z31 essentially just does a cumsum operation across the rows corresponding to each separate value of pred$LookupNum, using tapply, which allows you to apply the same function over different groups of rows (here, we're grouping by pred$LookupNum). The definition of pred$LookupNum helps enormously here - it's a numeric index with a block of 1s, followed by a block of 2s, and so on. This means the final list of cumsum vectors that comes out of the tapply can simply be unlisted and put into a vector and is automatically in the right order. If you do a tapply and split by groups that aren't ordered like this, you normally need a couple of additional lines of code to match things back up again correctly (though it isn't tricky).

Final observation: if the final tapply is too scary, it's worth highlighting that a quick loop over a small number of cases (48 say) isn't always disastrous if the work within the loop is nicely vectorised. The "alternative method" at the end of the UPDATE section shows that the cumsum-on-groups step can also be achieved by pre-preparing an answer column (initially all NAs) and then going through the 48 subsets one by one and filling in the each block with the appropriate cumsum. As noted in the text, though, this single step is roughly half the speed as the clever tapply approach, and if more subsets were needed this would be considerably slower.

If anyone has any follow up questions on this kind of task, please don't hesitate to give me a shout.

Comment: Looks promising. `match` strategy with pasted vectors looks to be O(n) in time versus the O(n^2) loop strategy using separate accesses to dataframes.

Comment: Looks like Est.Date is already in date format (original post didn't make it clear), so in my solution above Z31$estdate_tidy can be replaced by Z31$Est.Date (similarly for pred$date_tidy and pred$Date, if pred$Date is already in date rather than character format) :)

Comment: Thanks DWin - yes, expect the match strategy is optimal here. Should realise at least a 1000x speedup overall.

Comment: Wish I had sufficient points to contribute to the discussion below... but I expect looping is a terrible strategy here! Would be great to see some timing comparisons...

Comment: I did look briefly at merge but wasn't sure how to guarantee it correctly preserved order, which is essential here. My first few attempts seemed to mangle the order so I instead went for an approach guaranteed to work. What syntax for merge would work correctly here? Morally both approaches are one liners anyway (Z31_m and pred_m are defined separately just for clarity really).

Comment: Am mainly used to merging data in situations where row order matters so paste'n'match is force of habit really :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim. I'm fairly new to the vector way of doing things and I wan't able to get your example to work. I'm going to go with Sub's solution below for now, it runs fast enough now plus I can't really spend too much more time on this problem right now. I'll refer back to this in the future when I have more time to study it.

Comment: Hi Justin - that's a shame, I'm pretty sure the vector way would run in no more than a couple of seconds, rather than 15 mins or whatever you have now. To tie up the loose ends would you mind emailing a dump of the two objects to me (timp2012 AT hotmail.com) please so I can do a benchmark timing? Thanks... :)

Comment: As noted in my first comment above, if the dates are already in date rather than character format, you won't have to remap them... in which case just paste in the five commands below: `Z31_m = paste(Z31$Site, Z31$Cultivar, Z31$Planting)`;  `pred_m = paste(pred$Site, pred$Cultivar, pred$Planting)`;  `pred$Est.Date = Z31$Est.Date[match(pred_m, Z31_m)]`;  `pred$ttfilter = ifelse(pred$Date >= pred$Est.Date, pred$tt, 0)`;  `pred$cum_tt = cumsum(pred$ttfilter)`

Comment: Thanks for sending through the data objects. I think the reason that you had difficulties running my solution is that some of the (Site, Cultivar, Planting) combinations in pred don't actually occur in Z31 - in fact there are 96 different combinations in pred and only 48 in Z31. I was under the impression that Z31 comprised all the possible cases? For instance, pred$Cultivar can equal "Baudin" (there are 1446 such entries) but "Baudin" doesn't occur in Z31$Cultivar (or indeed anywhere in Z31). I'm pretty sure this means there's a fairly fundamental error somewhere here... :(

Comment: Oh yes.. I should have mentioned... These results are from a field trial where we looked at different varieties of wheat and barley. The barley didn't work out so well so it was excluded from the results. Baudin and the other missing varieties are barley. I've added the following lines to my code to remove barley from the predicted results: wheat <- c("Axe", "Bolac", "Derrimut", "Eaglehawk", "Gregory", "Lincoln", "Mace", "Scout"); pred <- pred[pred$Cultivar %in% wheat,]. I'll give your solution another try later today.

Comment: Ok... progress. It now works since I pulled the barley out of pred, but the problem is (and this wasn't really made clear by me, sorry) that TT is now accumulating for the entire data frame. It needs to reset for each Site/Cultivar/Planting combination.

Comment: Great stuff, we're getting there I think! When you come to run the code, remember these 3 things: (1) if the dates are in character format they'll need converting using strptime, as per my original code; (2) you need to ensure Planting is formatted consistently, as in the pred object you sent me it was coded as {TOS1,TOS2} rather than the Z31 coding of {1,2}; (3) finally the column tt was missing from the pred you sent me - though I imagine this is just the mean of mint and maxt. Finally - I know you want the "cum sum" here - but can I ask why? Should the data be sorted into date order first?

Comment: Just saw your post about TT accumulating... Once you've ensured that all the variable issues in my previous comment are sorted out, do you want to resend the objects so we're definitely talking the same language? Cheers :)

Comment: I must have sent you the raw data by mistake, sorry. I do some transforms on pred before it's operated on. I've sent you the right copy. This is why Planting comes through as text, though it can be cast to a number if needed. We use a slightly different formula for tt (which stands for Thermal Time) to capture variations through the day, but you're correct in that it's basically just daily mean temperature. The idea with the cum_tt is to get the cumulative thermal time for each Crop/Site/Planting combination.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, that about does it.  It's crazy how much faster R can do vector ops. I'll definantly be studying your code to apply it to future situations!

Comment: Thanks Justin, if you'd like any pointers just let me know. As a starting point, I'm going to add a few words on vectorization at the very end of my answer :)

Comment: @Tim P Are you sure a vector scanning approach using `paste` will scale to large data such as `1e7`, `1e8`, `1e9` rows?

Answer (score 1):

a quick solution is to define a vector  outside the loop as:

```
 temp_cumtt=c(rep(0,nrow(pred)))
```

and then  use this:

```
if (Z31[i,2] == pred[j,5] & Z31[i,3] == pred[j,4] & Z31[i,4] == pred[j,6] & pred[j,1] >= Z31[i,1]){
   temp_cumtt[j]=pred[j,7] + pred[j-1,8]
}
```

instead of updating the data.frame column directly.

After you come out of the loop, you can update the column:

```
 pred$cum_tt = temp_cumtt
```

The other thing is you have to be careful when using `j-1` with index of `j` starting at `1`. In your example it doesn't lead to that conditional-problem.

EDIT:

Now looking at your data-format, I have these suggestions.

1) Don't convert into `Date` class, instead keep it as a vector of values.

2) Sort the `Z31` data_frame according to Date-vector: `Z31=Z31[with(Z31, order(-Date)), ]` (Note in descending order since you want to compare pred[,Date index]>=Z31[,Date index]

3) Use the 1st loop as `pred`. First take the Date of pred -> `pred[i,1]` and try to binary sort and find which index in Z31 it satisfies and from that index onwards go down the list. If `Date` condition satisfies then check for the rest of the conditions and fill the `temp_cumtt[i]` as before.

This should be blazing fast (since binary sort only on 48 rows of `Z31` and you can compare the run time .with the other solution.

Comment: Thanks subs, that does improve execution speed, I'm down to about 15 secs per outside iteration, down from 60. I'm hopeing to be able to do this without loops at all though since they're so slow. Still, this is a big improvement. I'm not worried about the j-1 index since in the dataset I'm using the first row will never be true.

Comment: loops are not inefficient. It depends on what you do inside them. The other way is to sort your `Z31` data frame according to your `Date` and since the `Date` in `pred` is already sorted, you can check use an algorithm to start comparison from an index instead of going over all your Z rows * P rows

Comment: Thanks again subs. I need to move on with what I'm doing so I wasn't able to implement the binary sort technique. You've helped me speed it up to an acceptable level though. Some timings in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make use of `data.table`, which should speed things up a whole lot.

```
Z31 <- data.table(Z31,key="Site,Cultivar,Planting")
pred <- data.table(pred)

## First, let's create an extra column in `pred` to see the corresponding date from `Z31` 
## Note 1: The JT is necessary since both sets have the same column names
## Note 2: I needed to use as.integer on Planting to make it work

pred[,Z31Est.Date:={JT=J(Site,Cultivar,as.integer(Planting)); Z31[JT,Est.Date][[4]]}]

## Now we can see for each row whether the date in `pred` is higher than or equal to that from `Z31`.

pred[,DateTrue:=Date>=Z31Est.Date]

## Finally, we only have to add up `pred[i,tt]` and `pred[i-1,cum_tt]` for each row where `DateTrue` equals `TRUE`.

for (i in 1:nrow(pred)) set(pred,i,13L,if(pred[i,DateTrue]) pred[i-1,cum_tt]+pred[i,tt] else(0))
```

Comment: A 'solution' that still contains `for (i in 1:nrow(pred))` isn't really helpful - we already have a solution with full vectorisation.

Comment: The question was to speed up a loop, right? Well I think this speeds it up but I can't test whether it actually does. But indeed using a loop should be avoided.

Comment: I read the question as being... "I know loops are not R's strong point so can anyone assist me with vectorising this operation?" :)

Comment: @Dirk I can see what you were trying here. I suspect a shorter and simpler `data.table` solution is possible, though. Possibly even a one or two liner which should be faster than Tim's vectorisation using `paste` (which is usually the part that doesn't scale to `1e6`, `1e7` or `1e9` rows). I'll come back to this one day. We could do with a `1e7` example to demonstrate the timings.